# Big O calculation confused

Tags: big-o

I have this question for my exam, and I could not figure it out:
calculate the Big O for the following:

1)

```
 for i = 0 to n     // n - 0 + 2 = (n+2)
  for j = 0 to m    // m - 0 + 2 = (m+2)
   x = x + 1
```

so does the answer become (n+2)(m+2) with O(nm) as the bigO?

Answer (score 1):

it is O(nm)

I don't think your initial math is correct though

because you have `(n+1)(m+1)` but after you expand this you will get something like `m*n+m+n+1`
and since m*n is the highest order here you will get `O(m*n)`

Answer (score 1):

> so does the answer become (n+2)(m+2) with O(nm) as the bigO?

Why **n+2**? It would be **n+1** if **0 to n** contains **n**, or it would be **n**, if **n** is exclusive. Therefore run time would me **(n+1)(m+1)** or **(nm)**.

However, **O(nm)** would be in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

yes.

You have 2 loops. So you have O(outer * inner). The outer loop is executed about `n` times. The inner loop is executed bout `m` times.

So O(nm) is appropriate.